# Java - problems iterating through an ArrayList

Tags: java, collections, iterator

Ok, so I have an `ArrayList (arrBok)`, which is full of `book` objects (the code is in Norwegian, so pay no attention to that please). I want to make a public method which iterates through all the objects in the `ArrayList'.

When I execute the code, it just seems to run in an infinite loop, not producing any return values.

Here is the relevant (I hope, because there are a couple of other classes involved) part of the code;

```
public String listAll()
{
    itr = arrBok.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext())
    {
        i++;
    }
    return "lol";
}
```

This code does nothing useful, but I just want to see if it can iterate through it successfully.

What I have tried so far;

- Tested if the `bokArr (ArrayList)` is empty, which it's not. It has 4 objects inside of it.
- Return the `toString()` method of the `itr`, with the following result;

> java.util.AbstractList$Itr@173a10f // <-- not sure if this would be relevant to anything

- `return itr.next().toString();` <-- // which seems to return the first object in the array, does that make sense?

Comment: You didn't do "itr.next()" in your loop! That is "lol"!

Comment: I guess with the answers you figured out what went wrong, to avoid such pitfalls, you could use `foreach` construct which is available form `jdk >1.5`. you could do something like `for(Book b: arrBook){System.out.println (b);}`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That code as quoted won't compile, you're missing a couple of declarations. But I think I get the gist.

[`hasNext`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext()) tells you that the iterator *has* a next value, but doesn't take you to it. To do that, you use [`next`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next()). So that is an endless loop because you're never calling `next`.

With any recent compiler, you can use the much simpler notation for this:

```
for (Object book : arrBok) {
    // ...do something with 'book' (or just increment your counter)...
}
```

That iterates through the collection (list, in this case) for you.

Answer (score 7):

You simply forgot to "move" to the next element:

```
while (itr.hasNext()) {
   // Get next element
   Object o = itr.next();
   // do what you want with your element...
}
```

Note that since Java 5, you can iterate on a list using this syntax:

```
List<String> myList = getAListOfString();
for (String s : myList) {
    // Your code
}
```

Answer (score 5):

why not iterate like this:

```
for(Book book :arrBok){
  // do something
}
```

Comment: I would think this is best way if you are able to use Java 5 for-each loops and generics.

Answer (score 4):

You have to call `next()`:

```
public String listAll() {
  itr = arrBok.iterator();
  while (itr.hasNext()) {
    itr.next();
    i++;
  }
  return "lol";
}
```

On a side note, I'd strongly recommend you adopt the Java coding style (as in my example with opening braces on the same line).

You can use an `Iterator` but there *usually* isn't much point. Since Java 5 you can do this:

```
public String listAll() {
  for (Object ob : arrBok) {
    i++;
  }
  return "lol";
}
```

And for any `List` you've always been able to do this:

```
public String listAll() {
  for (int i=0; i<arrBok.length(); i++) {
    Object ob = arrBok.get(i);
  }
  return "lol";
}
```

which is efficient for `ArrayList` but not for `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
public String listAll()
{
    itr = arrBok.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext())
    {
        itr.next();
        i++;
    }
    return "lol";
}
```

you didn't actually iterate it. just check for next.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call itr.next() in the loop to move to the next element.

Also, i++ has no relevance in your code - it is just incrementing a variable that is not being used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

> return itr.next().toString(); <-- // which seems to return the first object in the array, does that make sense?

Yes, that makes sense. If you want to iterate through all items, you need to call `itr.hasNext()` **followed by** call to `itr.next()`. However, if you do `return itr.next().toString()` inside the loop, it cuts the loop short on the first iteration, and returns from the method immediately. So, do like [cletus said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454749/java-problems-iterating-through-an-arraylist/2454776#2454776).